# EditText not able to convert or not able fetch

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tusername);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tpassword);
    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    CheckBox show = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkme);
    if(show.isChecked()){

   password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

    }else{
        password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    }

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           String usern = username.getText().toString();
            settUsername(usern);
            Intent intent = new Intent("display");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
    public void settUsername(String u){
        usern = u;

    }

 public String getUsername(){
     return usern;
 }
```

This is my `login.java` where i am trying to fetch data from the `edittext`

```
public class display extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);

    TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usernd);
    Login l = new Login();
    String username = l.getUsername();
    v.setText("Welcome" + username);

}
}
```

`display.java` is where i am printing the data i fetched from edit text! But it is printing `null`. Can someone help me with this! i have even converted the data i fetched from the edittext using to string but still i am not able to print the data all it says is `null`

Comment: you should send data using Intents and get it in your next activity, dont use methods like this. to passing data always use Intents bundle

Comment: i tried using intent.putextra but it's still the same

Comment: Ok!, pls post your code for same. it will be more helpful

Comment: @SumanthJois: show your code which u have tried using `Intent.putExtra` ?

Comment: between how would you set the value of other activity's TextView using intent.putextra?? plz help

Comment: Some part of code is missing... where have you defined `usern` in the first class? And what do you expect to obtain with `Login l = new Login();`?

Comment: using the object of login i am fetching the data entered in edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pass data from one activity to another in the wrong way. You should use the built-in intent mechanism:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, display.class);
intent.putExtra("username", usern);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in you display activity you can retrieve it in this way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);

    TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usernd);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String username = myIntent.getStringExtra("username");
    v.setText("Welcome" + username);

}
```

Ps: I would also recommend to define class names starting with an upper case letter (e.g. `Display` and not `display`). This is not mandatory but it's a good practice that every java developer use to make the code clearer. Moreover you could also add extra information to your class name to let other developers better understand what your class is supposed to do (in this case I would use `DisplayActivity` instead of just `Display`).